# При делении выдает infinity

Tags: javascript

Всем привет.Я только начинаю изучать javascript.Было задание с использованием функций реализовать выполнение арифметических операций с проверкой деления на ноль. Усложнять код не нужно. Подскажите где ошибка, потому что все операции выполняет нормально, а при выполнении деления при любых данных выдает infinity. Вот код

```
function plus(a,b) {
    return a + b;
}
function minus(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}
function delenie(a,b) {
    return a / b;
}
function umnogenie(a,b) {
    return a * b;
}

var a = prompt("Введите первое число"),
    b = prompt("Введите второе число"),
    znak = prompt("Введите арифметический знак"),
    result = undefined;

    a = parseInt(a);
    b = parseInt(b);

switch(znak) {
    case "+" :
        {
        result = plus(a,b);
        break;
        }
    case "-" :
        {
        result = minus(a,b);
        break;
        }
    case "/" :
        {
        if (b = 0) {
            document.write("На ноль делить нельзя!");
        } else {
            result = delenie(a,b);
        }
        break;
    }
    case "*" :
        {
        result = umnogenie(a,b);
        break;
    }
        default :
    document.write("<span style='red'>" + znak + "Не является арифметическим знаком!</span>");
}
    document.write(result);
```

Comment: Фигурные скобки в case - писать не обязательно. И при вводе неизвестной операции у вас будет двойной вызов document.write, поэтому в секции default лучше присвоить result строку, которую вы сейчас передаете document.write

Comment: Благодарю за совет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Должно быть `if (b == 0)`, а не `if (b = 0)`

Ошибка в этом, потому что вы не проверяете, а каждый раз присваиваете b ноль и соответственно делите на ноль.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!Помогло.

Comment: @Deniskins, тогда прими ответ нажатием на галочку слева от него.

Comment: я ждал, когда даст на это разрешение-).Еще раз спасибо.